# 1С интеграция с сайтом

Tags: 1с

Добрый день.

Никогда не работал с 1С, но недавно поступил заказ в котором фигурирует 1С. Поэтому вопрос к экспертам:

Стоит задача реализовать сайт ( 2-3 странички), на котором пользователь сможет регистрироваться, заходить в свой аккаунт и смотреть информацию о себе ( фио, количество накопленных балов). Все данные на сайт и с сайта ( о регистрации) должным подтягиваться и отдаваться в 1С.

Вопрос: Как лучше реализовать такой функционал? Есть ли в 1с возможность получать и отдавать данные в режиме реального времени? Если да, подскажите в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 2):

Способ реализации, скорее всего, напрямую будет зависеть от того, каким боком 1С "фигурирует". Мало информации.

И уточните у заказчика, требуется ли режим реального времени, то есть на самом ли деле данные постоянно обновляются. Передача изменений не в режиме реального времени, а пакетами между 1С и сайтом, скажем, раз в минуту или раз в 15 минут - сильно упростит (и удешевит) решение.

Answer (score 1):

Решения которые работают в реальном времени в несколько раз дороже чем решения периодического обмена.

Решением для взаимодействия в реальном времени являются:

- SOAP сервис на стороне 1С:Предприятия, что позволит так же в автоматическом режиме сформировать прокси классы;
- OData интерфейс, ранее описал в [блоге](https://pbazeliuk.com/2015/10/01/1c-enterprise-odata/). Описал взаимодействие с Excel, C# и Android;
- HTTP сервис на базе 1С:Предприятия. Отсутствует возможность в автоматическом режиме сформировать прокси классы, но в то же время очень простые для реализации;
- Использовать для интеграции систему на базе очередей, например, RabbitMQ. Самое стабильное и отказоустойчивое, но и самое дорогое решение. Примерная стоимость подобного решения под ключ от 100 тыс. рублей.